# Invalid single-table inheritance type: Error when TRYING to set a STI subclass in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance, sti

This is my first time using single table inheritance.  I am trying to set subclasses for a blog Post using a select menu populated with a helper method.  I keep getting the same error when creating the Post record.

```
There is an Error: Invalid single-table inheritance type: News is not a subclass of Post
```

here are my models

post.erb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :event, -> { where(type: 'Event') } 
  scope :news, -> { where(type: 'News') } 
end
```

news_post.erb

```
class News < Post
end
```

event_post.erb

```
class Event < Post
end
```

post_helpers.erb

```
 def post_types
     [
      ['News'],
      ['Event'],
    ]
 end
```

_form.erb

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f| 
  = f.select(:type, post_types { },  {},  { multiple: false , class: " default_select form-control "  })
#rest of the form redacted
```

Is there something I'm missing that defines a subclass?  Again...first time doing this...

**UPDATE:**
Yes, there is a post.type column in the table schema.  it is a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to redefine your post_type method.

Better use a constant

```
 TYPES = %w( News, Event )
```

Comment: where do I put that? In the model?

Comment: This doesn't work when added to the post.rb.  I tried it with and without the comma.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `type` column to the `posts` table, it isn't added by default

-------Update------------

The reason might be that `News` model is plural, try telling rails that `news` is uncountable noun.

Add to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.uncountable %w( news )
end
```

Comment: I do have one.  I've updated my question to reflect.